# Can free() cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, destructor, free, delete-operator

Calling `delete` calls the destructor of a class, but calling `free()` does not.

Can that cause a memory leak? If not, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class x{
 public:
 int a;
 ~x(){cout<<"destroying"<<endl;}
};


int main() {
  x *y = (x*)malloc(sizeof(x));
  free(y);
  x *z = new x;
  delete z;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It has undefined behaviour, so it can cause anything or nothing at all.

Comment: `new` *must* be matched with `delete` (and `new[]` with `delete[]`). `free` is the match of `malloc`.

Comment: That's [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), see for example [Is it safe to free() memory allocated by new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406278/is-it-safe-to-free-memory-allocated-by-new).

Comment: *After* the edit, the line `x *y = malloc(sizeof(x));` won't even compile.

Comment: You know that [doesn't even compile?](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d026497cb286be0)

Comment: O yeah, I just saw that rn. I edited that without compiling, coz I thought that would create a new context of free with new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can that cause a memory leak?

In your particular example, no.  The `x` object is merely being *allocated* by `malloc()`.  `free()` will correctly *deallocate* the memory that `malloc()` allocated.  But the object will not be *destructed*, which is fine in this example because it was not *constructed* to begin with, so there is nothing to destruct.  However, if you try to use that object in any way that expects the constructor to have run, then you end up in *undefined behavior* territory.

C (where `malloc()` and `free()` come from) has no concept of classes, only of *memory (de)allocation*.  C++, on the other hand, has separate concepts of *memory (de)allocation* and *object (de)construction*, so you need to be very careful that you use them correctly and not mix them up incorrectly.

If an object were *constructed* via `new`, but then *deallocated* by `free()` rather than being *destructed* by `delete`, the code would definitely have *undefined behavior*, and if that object had internally allocated any additional memory for itself that the object's destructor is expected to free, that extra memory would be leaked, yes.

Comment: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete, this link might also be able to give more clarification, so im just gonna leave it here

Answer (score 1):

> Can free() cause a memory leak?

Not as such. But it can cause undefined behaviour. Of course, if the behaviour of the program is undefined, memory leak is among possible behaviour. As are all other behaviours.

Comment: if `x` owns memory, such as having a `std::string` memory, then it would indirectly result in a memory leak